# Is fully serializable, remote-working GUI framework possible?

Tags: .net, user-interface, serializable

Developing plugins (which include GUI) for some C# winforms application, I discovered that Winforms cannot work through application domain border. It requires controls to be MarshalByRef etc. So generally to upload a new plugin version, we need to restart application because we cannot unload former plugin.dll.

So my question is - is it possible to have fully serializable, remote-working GUI framework?

(Feel free if you can rephrase the question, I don't know how to express it shortly).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but a bit painful.

- Process -> creates AppDomain1
- AppDomain1 -> Creates AppDomain2 and loads the entry point which will load the application
- New pluggin arrives
- AppDomain1 unloads AppDomain2
- AppDomain1 loads new pluggin
- AppDomain1 Creates AppDomain2 and loads the entry point which will load the application

This of course involves reloading but you can take care of where things were last in your app.

Comment: GUI will not work through AppDomain border, Controls are not MarshalByRef

Comment: Of course they are not `MarshalByRef ` but even if they were, it would make no sense at all to host them on a server, they are `windows` forms controls that are based on WIN32 API and WIN32 message loop and all that. Impossible to host them.